# Mule FTP transport failing when deleting file

Tags: ftp, mule

I have an FTP endpoint polling to an FTP folder for new files. Due to concurrency issues we have when processing the files, we decided to have only one active thread for the FTP connector:

```
<ftp:connector name="ftp" doc:name="FTP" pollingFrequency="1000" validateConnections="true">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1" maxBufferSize="1000" />
    <reconnect count="5" frequency="1000"/>
</ftp:connector>
```

The problem we have is that the process we perform on the files can take up to several minutes, which makes the FTP connection to time out, so when the flow completes and the FTP connector tries to finally delete the file, we get an exception because the connection timed out.

My guess is that the FTP endpoint should validate the connection before trying to delete the file, but it doesn't look like doing that.

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: I had a similar issue, and used a component at the end of the flow to delete the file on the source ftp location, the component was placed at the end of the flow, have you considered this option ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the flow processing strategy to `synchronous` to mobilize the polling thread and do the processing with it, so it won't be able to poll again to early.

Comment: I had set it to synchronous. The problem is that, after all the processing is done, when the FTP endpoints try to delete the file, the connection is already timed out, so it fails.

Comment: Are you OK deleting the file even if the processing fails? If yes, then use an `object-to-byte-array` transformer after the `ftp:inbound` and put your processing code in an `<async>` block, that way it won't block the FTP thread.

Comment: Yes, I was doing this. But as we have concurrency issues I had to create a queue and process one by one. What I don't like is that it will read all files, delete them and then if something goes wrong those files will be lost. I'm thinking on first moving the original file to different locations in the FTP and have a FTP endpoint polling a different folder. If anything goes wrong I still have the file in another folder and can copy it to a kind of 'error' folder for later analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As FTP connection can timeout, I'd rather copy files from FTP to File location before starting to process them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I cannot copy the file to a local folder because the app will be deployed in an environment where I don't have access to the file system. Thanks anyway.